# Cypress soaking up all available memory

Tags: cypress

I'm having serious issues with Cypress soaking up all my available memory (16Gb). I have 30+ tests and if I attempt to run them through the UI all at once then Cypress gradually uses all my available memory and then typically fails with a test timeout error. Closing the Cypress UI always recovers all the memory. I've seen https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/431 which suggests setting `numTestsKeptInMemory` to 0 but this makes no difference, also running in headless mode with `cypress run` makes no difference either: Ultimately all my memory get soaked up.

Also during development of the tests I've been using `it.only` but even when running only one test at a time the memory gradually gets soaked up until restarting Cypress is needed.

I'm using Cypress 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 (elementaryOS Loki)

Does anyone else have the same trouble?

Comment: This is a known issue with cypress https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2366 related to snapshotting and projects with a lot of external CSS

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming this is happening while using `cypress open`?

`cypress open` is used for TDD, so you can get immediate feedback while you're developing. It's recommended in the docs to NOT run all your tests in the test runner, but with `cypress run` instead.

You won't get to do the snapshot history navigating, and instead will only get pictures and a video recording, but your tests will run in a headless browser and not soak up your memory.

PS: If you need to fix a broken test and want to use the test runner, you can isolate it using `it.only('test case...)`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add a reference link for "It's recommended in the docs to NOT run all your tests in the test runner, but with cypress run instead."

Comment: I've been using `it.only` to run only a handful of tests at most, yet Cypress _on the first run_ uses up ~8 GB of memory and dies a while later after using all remaining memory ~20 GB total for Cypress alone. Crashing every 30-40 minutes from running out of memory isn't what I'd expect for something made for TDD.